Langchain - VectorStores: Efficent Embeddings Compression
I am working on compressing a VectorStore for embeddings to make our database smaller and more efficient. My objective is to manage embeddings dynamically—both during loading and while running the system—so that documents can be updated over time without strictly maintaining their uniqueness by IDs.
From the documentation I've reviewed on EmbeddingsRedundantFilter and contextual compression, it appears that embedding/documents compression is recommended during the document retrieval phase to reduce redundancy and improve context.
An alternative I considered involves enforcing document uniqueness by IDs during loading, similar to what's described in this StackOverflow discussion. However, this method does not fit my use case as it fails to handle frequent updates to the same document.
I'm exploring another strategy: maintaining a complete index of already loaded documents and recalculating the entire VectorStore's embeddings whenever a new document is loaded. The idea is to compute embeddings from document text, adding them to the VectorStore only if they meet a certain similarity threshold—ensuring they provide new information.
Question: Is it feasible to implement a system that dynamically compresses embeddings during loading based on what's already present in the vectorstore to eliminate redundancy based on embedding similarity?
What are the technical challenges, if any, associated with such an approach?
